# Grafana regex to ignore the asterisk as the first character in labels

Tags: regex, grafana, prometheus

I have Grafana 5.2 dashboards sourcing data from Prometheus.

I have some labels in a dashboard that seem to be in the format `*.<domain>` for e.g. `*.google.com` e.t.c however, this doesn't play with Grafana without some smart regex to ignore the first two characters.

I have the following regex `(?<=^\*\.|^)[-a-zA-Z0-9._ ]+` which doesn't seem to work in Grafana but works in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eG8uP2/3). It should result in the label as `google.com` i.e. without the first two characters `*.`.

[image: Without regex]

[image: With regex]

Can someone please let me know what causes this ?

Comment: Try using a capturing group - `^(?:\*\.)?([-a-zA-Z0-9._ ]+)`

Comment: I assume this is because Grafana doesn't support lookbehinds. You could try using `\K` to reset the match  `^(?:\*\.)?\K[-a-zA-Z0-9._ ]+`. [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eG8uP2/5).

Comment: Also, the placeholder in that field suggests regex delimiters, and if they are required, try `/^(?:\*\.)?([-a-zA-Z0-9._ ]+)/`. Or, if it is PCRE/Boost/Onigmo powered, use `/^(?:\*\.)?\K[-a-zA-Z0-9._ ]+/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your first suggestion seems to have worked. I guess Grafana look* type regex. Thanks for the tip. Also feel free to add it as an answer so i can mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Grafana documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/), you may capture the part of a regex to return that substring:

> Filter and modify the options using a regex capture group to return part of the text:
>   Regex:
>
> `/.*(01|02)/`
>
> Result:
>
> ```
> 01
> 02
> ```

Hence, you may use

```
^(?:\*\.)?([-a-zA-Z0-9._ ]+)
          ^                ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uK72kT/1).

Here,

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:\*\.)?` - an optional (due to `?` quantifier that matches 1 or 0 sequences) [**non-capturing** group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) that matches a `*.` substring (1 or 0 times)
- `([-a-zA-Z0-9._ ]+)` - a [**capturing** group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that matches 1+ ASCII letters, digits, `-`, `.`, `_` and space and places its matched value into Group 1 and returns it in Grafana as a result of a match.