# Grafana Regex Issue

Tags: regex, grafana

I am trying to parse a word before ':' character.
I mean i want to get 10.10.10.10 from 10.10.10.10:9445. I tried on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YKnxvY/1). It worked there. But couldn't get what i want on grafana.I searched and tried but couldn't achieve what i want. Grafana doesn't throw error on that regex but also doesn't return result.

Can someone please let me know what causes this ?

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52363955/grafana-regex-to-ignore-the-asterisk-as-the-first-character-in-labels)

Comment: I think `^([^:]+)` will work. If you must check for `:`, use ``^([^:]+):``

Comment: Similar issue. Work on regex101 like charm but not on grafana.

Comment: It is possible it is using ES5 regex flavor then, try `([^:]+):.*`

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you post the answer? SO i can remark as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a regex that matches the full string and use a capturing group around the part of pattern you need to get:

```
([^:]+):.*
```

It will match and capture any 1 or more chars other than `:` from the start of the string till the first `:`, then will match `:` and any 0 or more chars other than line break chars till end of the string (with no linebreaks).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YKnxvY/2).